# Query with 3 tables with same common field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables like these:

FILE_INF

```
ORDER
STARTRUN
ENDRUN
NAME
```

FILE_RUN

```
ORDER
GROUP
```

FILE_LOG

```
ORDER
MESSAGE
DATE
```

The three tables have a lot of registers with column `ORDER`, but there is a uniq register with `ORDER` and `MESSAGE` columns (table `FILE_LOG`), but I need more data that there is no in table `FILE_LOG`.
I'm trying with these query but it gives more than one register.

```
SELECT A.NAME,
  A.STARTRUN, 
  A.ENDRUN, 
  B.GROUP, 
  C.MESSAGE,
  C.DATE
FROM FILE_INF A inner join
  FILE_RUN B ON A.ORDER = B.ORDER inner join 
  FILE_LOG C ON B.ORDER = C.ORDER AND 
    A.STARTRUN >= '20190729000000' AND 
    A.ENDRUN <= '20190729235959' AND 
    C.MESSAGE like '%FILE ORDERED%'
ORDER BY A.STARTRUN,
  A.ENDRUN;
```

Someone could help me to extract the correct information?

```
Imagine:

FILE_INF
ORDER  STARTRUN         ENDRUN          NAME
11     20190729000100   20190729010100  APPLE
11     20190729020000   20190729030000  APPLE
.........

FILE_RUN
ORDER  GROUP
11     FRUITS
11     FRUITS
.....

FILE_LOG
ORDER  MESSAGE                     DATE
11     FILE ORDERED SUCCESFULLY    20190928
11     FILE_NOT_ORDERED            20190928
11     FILE_NOT_FOUND              20190928

My desire result should be:

ORDER  MESSAGE                     DATE        GROUP
11     FILE_ORDERED_SUCCESFULLY    20190928    FRUITS
```

Comment: You can more than one matching row in one or more of the tables.  Nothing mysterious.

Comment: What do you mean with "registers"?

Comment: That's how inner joins work. If you have multiple matching rows in other tables, the "result set" will show multiple rows for the same order. You better provide some sample data, and the expected result you want. Otherwise this questions risks to be closed because of its low quality.

Comment: Please indicate what the primary key columns are in each of the tables.  If two of the three are not identical, you may need to think about how to avoid / deal with a fan-trap situation.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Model_usability_issues)

Comment: with register I mean rows sorry for my english

Comment: I edit the main post with the expected result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ORDER is not a unique value, many rows have the same value of 11.  When you do a join using ORDER, you will get all the rows where ORDER = 11, which is multiple rows in every table in your example.

You cannot join on ORDER and get only one row as a result if ORDER is not a unique value.

The only way for you to get one row as a result would be if there were no repeat values in ORDER for each table.  For example if this was your data:

```
FILE_INF
ORDER  STARTRUN         ENDRUN          NAME
11     20190729000100   20190729010100  APPLE
12     20190729020000   20190729030000  APPLE
.........

FILE_RUN
ORDER  GROUP
11     FRUITS
12     FRUITS
.....

FILE_LOG
ORDER  MESSAGE                     DATE
11     FILE ORDERED SUCCESFULLY    20190928
12     FILE_NOT_ORDERED            20190928
13     FILE_NOT_FOUND              20190928
```

Then you would return only 1 row when you join on ORDER.